# Place MATLAB contour plot on any plane

Tags: matlab, contour

I have a 3d plot and I'd like to put a 2d contour plot in a vertical (XZ) plane. When I place a contour plot, it always places it on a XY plane. If it were a pcolor, I could swap the YData and ZData using a set and a get, which works fine. Only I want the contour plot, not a pcolor.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Maybe `contourslice` could help: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/contourslice.html

Comment: I couldn't get contourslice to work if I only have 2d data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 2D data, just extrapolate it out to make it 3D, by repeating it in the `Y` direction (in this case).

```
% Sample data
m=-1:1:1;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(m)
Z=X+Y

% Create the 3D position grids
[xx,yy,zz]=meshgrid(m)
% Copy the data the appropriate number of times
vv=repmat(Z,[1 1 length(m)])
% permute dimensions so that everything is constant in the second (Y) dimension
vv=permute(vv,[1 3 2])

contourslice(xx,yy,zz,vv,[],[0 0],[])
view([30 20])
```